# Thunderbird, view Microsoft Teams invitation as HTML and not as URL

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird client and when I receive a Microsoft Teams invitation, I see it as an URL, and not as the typical Gmail view, with date, hour and meeting users embedded in mail content.

How can I accomplish this with Thunderbird ?

Comment: Check the "Message source code" (menu view) of the e-mail. Especially invitations received via Office365 + IMAP do no contain the information you are searching. On Office265 there is on option on server side how invitations are sent.